# Javascript (AngularJS) don't block UI during large DOM update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

In my angular app, I have an operation that has the potential to add tens of thousands of elements to the DOM every time it gets run (which happens every time the user pastes new data into a textarea.

On occasions when it has to add, say, 20,000 table rows to a table, it just blocks the whole page (spinning beach ball) for about ten seconds.

Is there a way around to not have it block the UI? (A way besides just *not* adding all the elements to the DOM: since that's the core functionality of this particular app)

My next thought was this: what if I hide the table until all the in-memory DOM manipulation is done, then show it again?

Because, I know that updating the DOM is actually a two stage process: 1) update all the elements in memory, then 2) re-render the affected section of the page.

Is it possible to receive a callback *after* the DOM manipulation is finished in memory?

Any other thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is the relevant code

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in enormousArray">
        <td ng-repeat="value in row">{{value}}</td>
    <tr>
<table>
```

And the javscript:

```
$scope.someEventsHappen = function(dataString){
    var my2DArray = MyService.functionThatProcessesAStringIntoAnArray(dataString);
    $scope.enormousArray = my2DArray;
}
```

NOTE: 1) these aren't the names of the actual functions and variables in my code, so please no lectures about naming conventions, and 2) I'm actually using 'controller as' in my code, but I translated it to $scope for simplicity's sake.

EDIT 2: After doing some more reading, I think my next step is to create a custom directive so that I can control when and how the data gets bound in the link step. I'll post my results here when I get it finished, and if it yields useful information.

Comment: No user can consume 20,000 rows and that's a significant number of dom elements to load in the browser. Why would you ever need that many rows displayed in the first place?

Comment: maybe use pagination?

Comment: "add tens of thousands of elements to the DOM" - you're doing it wrong.

Comment: So, I appreciate the advice, but I'm not asking a UX question. I know there are ways I could put less data on the page and make the data more accessible at the same time, and I'm pretty sure that's what I'm going to end up doing. But, I'm asking a pure javascript question. I'm seeking a better understanding of the way the browser works under the hood. Please, no more answers scolding me for not doing it the way you would do it.

Comment: you can also use limitTo, and infinity scrolling for better performance

Comment: also one-time binding could help too

Comment: also there is a good thread on this on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/2cvgou/angularjs_with_large_data/)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your rows to an object instead of the dom. Then when the operation is completed drop all of the changes into the dom at once. If you are adding each element to the dom one at a time, then the browser has to re-parse / re-draw 20,000 times. You should try building up the table without touching the dom.

Comment: Sorry. I should have been more clear. I'm not manipulating the DOM directly. I'm just assigning a 2-dimensional array to an object on the scope and letting Angular do the DOM manipulation. I'll post the relevant code.

Comment: I'm willing to bet Angular is still updating the dom for each row. Maybe try storing it to a different property in the scope until the process is complete, then assign the array to the property you have your template bound to.

Also, lots of data in js isn't a problem. Displaying all of it at once becomes difficult for the user though and you might want to consider some ways to filter it. Here's an example with over 200,000 data points, 
http://square.github.io/crossfilter/

Answer (score 0):

To hide DOM elements while loading, you can use ngCloak. However, what you're doing isn't the right way to approach this. If you're loading "tens of thousands" of elements, you're not giving your user a prayer of viewing your page in a useful manner. You need to figure out what it is they **really need to see** and how you can deliver that in a way that makes sense. No one is looking over 20k records for any reason on a web page.